# Is it possible to use a raspberry-pi as a stand alone device to run Nmap programmes regularly?

Tags: networking, pi-4

Apparently, I plan on using the device to scan a particular network and to output results to a server, but would it be possible to leave the pi as a stand-alone device and to leave it scanning the network on regular basis?

Any suggestions anyone?

thanks,
Jay.

Comment: What makes you it may not be possible?

Comment: If you have a simple script, you can use `cron` to run it often.  A Pi4 would be a bit of an overkill for this - a Zero W runs my monitoring fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently I started using a Pi 4 for doing regular `nmap` scans, as Ingo points out of course it is perfectly suited to this (though as Andrew points out any model should be fine).

I noticed that eg., the default 1000 port syn stealth scan can take a very widely varying amount of time on a LAN w/ about a dozen devices on it -- sometimes it completed in a minute or two, sometimes it would run *for hours* without completing, and when it did the content was much the same, ie., the delay was not because it ended up doing a more thorough job.

I think a factor was using an interface that was also in general use -- eg. I ssh in.  What I settled on was adding a second wifi adapter and isolating it with LXC and network namespaces.  In brief:

- Second adapter isolated via net namespaces:

  ```
    ip netns add nmap
    iw phy phy1 set netns name nmap
  ```
- LXC container is then started in the `nmap` namespace via `ip netns exec ...`,
  running a full OS (you can use pretty much any linux distro) w/systemd and dhcpcd, but no networking running by default.  This on top of the host Rpi OS buster system (headless) still only takes ~300 MB of RAM (that's for *both*).<sup>1</sup>  There's maybe a dozen processes total running in the container, most of them aren't doing anything and could be eliminated (eg., multiple `agetty`s waiting for logins that will never come).
- Timer task starts dhcpcd on the wifi every N hours.
- DHCP hook starts nmap via a forked wrapper when the interface comes online.
- Nmap outputs XML I then crunch into an SQL db :)
- When `nmap` exits the wrapper shuts dhcpcd down.

If you aren't using it for anything else, you obviously don't need to do all that (but really it is not all that much once you get the basics of LXC and net namespaces).

---

1. So, again, this could be done easily with any model including a zero.

Answer (score 3):

The [official supported Raspberry Pi OS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/) for all Raspberry Pis is a flavor of the **Debian** Distribution. So it has complete networking support with dual stack IPv4 and IPv6 and all features that are supported by Linux. It is no problem to run `nmap` on top of the network stacks. Depending on the version of the Raspberry Pi It is less or more a full featured embedded Linux computer with no problem to run as stand-alone device and doing its work by scanning the network. You can use the Raspberry Pi OS Lite version without the unneeded overhead of a graphical user interface. You can program `cron` or a `systemd` timer to scan the network regularly.